# Vinyl plank flooring

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring

How is a mechanical click and lock waterproof but the adhesive-to-adhesive style is water resistant. Chemical seems more resilient than mechanical, esp. with MDF.

I put the adhesive-to-adhesive style in the kitchen at my last house because my dog peed in there every night. My current dog is getting old and has started peeing in the carpeted areas. I hate carpet anyways, so the vinyl plank floor seems like a good idea again.

I asked the gal in the flooring section how the click and lock was waterproof but the adhesive-to-adhesive is only water resistant. She just parroted words from a pamphlet.

Comment: Perhaps they treat the mechanical joints that then seal on contact over time... WAG though.

Comment: One such brand/model had some sort of rubber gasket that made a seal, but a lot of the samples I looked at were simply some variation of a tongue and groove. The top is vinyl, but the material that's secured to looks like MDF. If you sneeze on MDF it'll swell.